# Instance of WebDriverWait method doesn't generates Template Proposals in Eclipse as before

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, content-assist

I have a small program that is supposed to click on something and then wait. Somehow, I don't get now the suggestions (code completion) as I did before, after I type the dot and wait.

Here is a small part of the program:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(StartRenderedButton)).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10); 
wait.unt
```

these imports i made:

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Nothing is suggested.

I tried to install new IDE, tried to change at the editor>advanced but nothing helped.

How i can get it back?

Comment: _...don't get now the suggestions..._ were you getting it earlier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, To turn on/ ensure Auto Suggestion on Eclipse IDE is enabled already, go to

> Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Auto
>   Activation Section

and make sure you have the following settings:

- Auto activation delay (ms):  `0`
- Auto activation triggers for Java :   `.`

**Pro tip:** If you want auto suggestion to pop up for all the alphabets as you get for ".", then enter "`.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy`" in Auto activation triggers for Java.

Second, you need a WebElement reference to use explicit wait [=wait.until...], something like,

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")
```

Source: [seleniumhq -docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: the solution as it looks was the .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
all the rest was as before.
about the  WebElement reference, it is written exactly like that so no difference over mine

Answer (score 0):

@Dhamo's answer was in the right direction.

To enable *Auto Suggestions* within your IDE (i.e. *Eclipse*) you need the following settings:

[image: Eclipse_Auto_Suggestion]

Perhaps you don't need the *Auto Suggestions* to popup for the *pattern matched* methods. So we can avoid setting:

```
Auto activation triggers for Java: .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
```

And keep it as:

```
- Auto activation triggers for Java: .
```

---

### Content Assist - Template Proposals

While typing a *Class* / *Method* name to view the *Template Proposals* dynamically you can press the following set of *Keys*:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>

The *Template Proposals* will get visible as follows:

[image: Eclipse_Template_Proposals]

Comment: sysout works, the only thing that didn't worked was the wait , strange but these is the situation

Comment: the answer of Dhamo was the right one as i needed to add Auto activation triggers for Java: .abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
and these is what was trigged the suggestions